# How can I quantify test-retest reliability with three waves of measurement?

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons, reliability, agreement-statistics

I tested subjects and repeated the test 2 times, so I did it 3 times in total. 
My question is: does anyone know how to evaluate the test-retest reliability? Is there another method (besides test-retest). All I can find are the correlations between 2 tests, never more.

Comment: You may read the section "Common kappa-like variants for 3 or more coders" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3402032/, and if you use r, try kappam.light / kappam.fleiss. Or ICC if your measures are continuous...

Answer (score 1):

Format your data in a subject-by-time matrix as below (without the headers). If your data is continuous, you should feed this matrix into a function that calculates the [intraclass correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) (ICC). There are multiple types of ICC, so make sure you use a two-way model. This will quantify how consistent your ratings were across the three time points. If your data is categorical, you should feed this matrix into a function that calculates a chance-adjusted agreement index using a generalized formula. One possible example would be [Fleiss' kappa coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss'_kappa).

```
Continuous Example:
   T1 T2 T3
S1 10 11 10
S2 09 13 15
S3 20 14 21
...

Categorical Example:
   T1 T2 T3
S1  1  2  1
S2  3  3  3
S3  2  2  1
...
```